# no access to preivous databases in mysql56 after password reset, but showing in data folder

Tags: mysql, windows-7, database-restore

i had problem with mysql (windows machine, mysql5.6) login because of power failure, after trying various solution, i did password reset for root. This helped me to login mysql using root account. But when, I issued `show databases;` i could see some database names missing from it.
So i went in `datadir="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\"` (per my.ini file)there I could found files of my missing databases.
Can anyone help me getting access to this missing databases or could explain reason behind their disappearance.

thanks for your time.

Comment: Reason (apparently): power failure. I'm sure you have backups. You should try to simply recover the crashed ones before going back to the backups.

Comment: I myself did not made any backup, nor I know how to do it in mysql. Does mysql auto backups data as windows does using system restore at some/critical points? If yes, then how could i use those backups to restore my databases.
Currently reading on how to backup/restore in mysql ;-)
And how do I recover crashed data?

Comment: At least you're honest. Check out the `mysqlcheck` command.